# Python: How to provide callable function name through variable at T1=Thread(target=<func_name>

Tags: python, multithreading, callable

Problem : 
I am using Threading module of Python and I need the implement a function where I can pass variable for function name at `Thread(target=<function name>)`
code snippet :
from threading import Thread

```
t1 = Thread(target=func_name, args=["testString"])
```

here I am getting error that '`Str is not callable`'
is there a way for converting str into callable?

Comment: Why are you not passing a callable in the first place?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a function as `target` not its name:

```
def some_func(...):
    # ...

Thread(target=some_func)   # right
Thread(target='some_func') # wrong
```

Python tries to call whatever you are passing as `target` and strings are not callable.